# Laravel qrcode return weird symbol when format to png

Tags: laravel, imagick

I'm trying to genereate qrcode using `https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode` in Laravel. It's already working if I'm using svg format, but when I'm using png. It will return  this:

```
�PNG  IHDR,,\ѩgAMA���a cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q<bKGD���̿IDATx��]lT��wY;��1ަ�2MY��tM��!Bn!j����LJ"��%�<�����ơy�b0��*U��OYJ����F��H��٪�`;����ۗ�s���ܹ�����ptf����^f�|�BAI_�$I��H�:��Jn`cJ�洜���Ͷ�Pw_P��*,�,�,��`-�_��Yo����`�~]0�2{�X���5��{��A�l�*
```

[image: result qr]

I've installed imagick on my windows, I don't know why this is happening

This is my controller:

```
 public function print_qr($id)
    {
        $location = LocationLibrary::find($id);
        $qrcode = QrCode::format('png')->size(300)->generate($location->id);
        return view('location-library.qr-code', compact('qrcode', 'location'));
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
<div id="qr-content" style="padding: 20px">
    <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold">QR Code For {{ $location->location_name }}</p>
       {!! $qrcode !!}
</div>
```

[image: php info]

[image: php info]

Comment: Try this in view: <img src="{{ $message->embedData($qrcode, 'nameForAttachment.png') }}" />
you can read more about embedData here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

Comment: In a earlier question you outputted as svg, that worked fine, why did you change it to png?

Comment: As @Kamran Khalid proposed, you will need to create an image element with a data URL. In your code example you see weird characters, because you're trying to echo the png binary data directly – won't work.

Comment: @Catto - I think the error is the content type isn't being set, so the browser doesn't know it's a PNG image. You may need to set it yourself with $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');`